# jQuery.ajax POST to Script to Update MySQL function not defined

Tags: php, jquery

I have the below function defined that passes a dynamic id to the function as a parameter and output to an html link. The script it calls updates a database record and returns an alert of success or failure based on query being successful, or the id failing some validation.

```
     function cancel_file(id){  
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://www.mysite.com/cancel.php",
            data: 'id='+ id,
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);

                if(response == 1){
                    alert('File successfully cancelled!');
                    }
                }
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response);

                if(response == "invalid_id"){
                    alert('The file ID format is invalid');
                }else if(response == "no_record_found"){
                    alert('No file found with ID specified');
                }

            }
        });
    }
```

And I am calling it in the  section of my document as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

The link on the page is output using the following php code

```
<?php echo "<a href='#' onclick='cancel_file(".$id.")'>Cancel </a>"; ?>
```

When the link is clicked nothing happens and when I examine the Chrome JS Debugger Console it shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: cancel_file is not defined". I did some reading that functions defined within the document.ready() are ignored by Chrome and FF so I removed that declaration from the top. I am still new to jQuery so any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA

cancel.php

```
<?php

// Get the fileid and make sure it's in a valid format
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if(!ctype_digit($id)){
        $response = "invalid_id";
    }else{
        // If validation passes proceed to queries and cancellation process
            $q1 = "UPDATE `table_files` SET `is_invalid` = 1 WHERE `id` = '".$id."'";
            $r1 = mysql_query($q1) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
            $response = mysql_affected_rows();
        }else{
            $response = "no_record_found";
    }

    echo $response;
?>
```

$response is what should be passed back to the jQuery function.

Comment: Why are you loading JQuery 2 times?

Comment: He's not, he's loading jQuery and jQuery UI two different things. The articles about document.ready being ignored by Chrome must be old, it works fine. Silly question but that jQuery is inside script tags right?

Comment: @RickCalder jquery.js does not have the script definitions because I load the actual file in my <HEAD> section using

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

Comment: I wasn't asking about that, I was asking about the script with the function you're trying to call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround by loading the PHP script into a jQuery UI modal and processed it there. Not exactly what I was hoping but it does the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your ajax call between your success function & error function (although that may be a copy/paste issue).

Other than that, instead of having a global function would binding to the link's click event be acceptable?

For example:

```
jQuery('.cancel-trigger').on('click', function(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.mysite.com/cancel.php",
        data: {
            id: jQuery(this).data('fileid')
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            if(response == 1){
                alert('File successfully cancelled!');
                }
            }
            else if(response == "invalid_id"){
                alert('The file ID format is invalid');
            }else if(response == "no_record_found"){
                alert('No file found with ID specified');
            }
        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            // this would run on an actual js/ajax error
        }
    });
});
```

Then with your link you can echo the following:

```
<?php echo '<a href="#" data-fileid="' . $id . '" class="cancel-trigger">Cancel </a>'; ?>
```

That way you have no global function and can pass in the id using data attributes instead of inline onclick events.

Comment: This gets rid of the errors in my Javascript Debugger but I'm getting no alert which makes me thing that something isn't working properly on my cancel.php script. I have edited my original post to include that code.

Comment: What shows up in your console? Both the error & success function should show something in the console.

Comment: Nothing. I have put a link to a screenshot:

http://www.imgjoe.com/x/jsdebugger.png

Comment: What about your network tab of the console? You should see if the request was even made, and what came back from the server.

Comment: I cleared my cache and re-ran it. Here are the updated screenshots

Debug Console:
http://www.imgjoe.com/x/jsdebugconso.png

Debug Network Tab
http://www.imgjoe.com/x/jsdebugnetwo.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove " ?> " from the last in ajax.Check if there is any space?

Comment: The ?> is the closing php tag that echoes the link. There are no ? in any ajax or jQuery statements. Looking at the javascript debugger I'm getting a HTTP Error Code 500: Internal Server Error and the response is empty.